# Convert a SQL query to Hibernate Criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria-api

Hi
 Scenario I'm working on is similar to twitter. What I want to do is get get the statues of followed users using hibernate criteria API.

Classes used:
`User` (This one has a many to many relationship to itself mapped by follow table)

`Status` (This one has a foreign key of user who put that)

If I'm to write it in a plain old sql this would be it.

```
select * from status where status.user_id IN(select follow_id from follow where follow.user_id = 1)
```

How to achieve this result using Hibernate Criteria API?

```
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "user", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "user_name")})
@Entity
public class TweeUser implements Serializable {
    private int id;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    @Basic
    public String getUserName() {
        return this.userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    private String fullName;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "full_name")
    @Basic
    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    private String email;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "email")
    @Basic
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    private String password;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "password")
    @Basic
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    private Set<TweeUser> followingUsers;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "follow", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "follow_id")},
            uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id", "follow_id"})})

    public Set<TweeUser> getFollowingUsers() {
        return followingUsers;
    }

    public void setFollowingUsers(Set<TweeUser> followingUsers) {
        this.followingUsers = followingUsers;
    }
}
```

Status Entity

```
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "status")
    @Entity
    public class TweeStatus implements Serializable{
        private int id;

        @javax.persistence.Column(name = "id")
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        private String rawStatus;

        @javax.persistence.Column(name = "raw_status")
        @Basic
        public String getRawStatus() {
            return rawStatus;
        }

        public void setRawStatus(String rawStatus) {
            this.rawStatus = rawStatus;
        }

        private Date createTime;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @javax.persistence.Column(name = "create_time")
        @Basic
        public Date getCreateTime() {
            return createTime;
        }

        public void setCreateTime(Date createTime) {
            this.createTime = createTime;
        }

        private TweeUser tweeUser;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
        public TweeUser getTweeUser(){
            return tweeUser;
        }

        public void setTweeUser(TweeUser tweeUser){
            this.tweeUser = tweeUser;
        }

        private Set<TweeHashTag> tweeHashTags;

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name = "status_hash", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "status_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "hash_id")},uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint( columnNames = { "status_id", "hash_id" } ) })
        public Set<TweeHashTag> getTweeHashTags(){
            return tweeHashTags;
        }

        public void setTweeHashTags(Set<TweeHashTag> tweeHashTags){
            this.tweeHashTags = tweeHashTags;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got the answer to this question. It was fairly simple. So here it goes.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(TweeStatus.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("tweeUser",tweeUser.getFollowingUsers()));
List statuses = criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 1):

You failed to provide the code of your Entities. If you do, maybe we can help you better.
My initial thoughts are that it is generally not a good idea to have an Entity with @ManyToMany relations to itself.
My first suggestion is to take a look at this post and maybe reconsider your db design:

[How to define many-to-many to itself in JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207935/how-to-define-many-to-many-to-itself-in-jpa)

Comment: I have added the sources. Well I have already done few operations with User entity. So don't know if I'll be able to change the design. But I'll look on that too. And I would be glad if you can point me out what changes I have to do.